# How do I add metadata to a Realms DAO community token?

Tags: fungible-token, metaplex

As per [Solana Labs token-list instructions](https://github.com/solana-labs/token-list#adding-a-new-token), now it's done with Metaplex tools. Trying to do that with [Strata update token tool](https://app.strataprotocol.com/edit-metadata), but my address is not the mint authority, the token was issued using DAO voting.

```
Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s invoke [1]
Program log: Instruction: Create Metadata Accounts v2
Program log: Mint authority provided does not match the authority on the mint
```

https://solscan.io/tx/4CaRy3Ybf5aYx5aMYygdGvVfpXrgK9ZzHNbub2nSGJjFQyBvHAfwEyRPbvvSeV4Z2J4GU3nLj4dud4cqf2bGozFq

Does that mean I need to pick "Execute Custom Instruction" for a Realms voting? Is there an easy way to get a serialized tx from a UI?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating and updating token metadata will be done by default through Realms in the future, relying on completion of [this pull request](https://github.com/solana-labs/governance-ui/pull/828).

Comment: Used the autodeployed "Preview – governance-ui" link from the PR, it worked - I create the proposal. Will update after executing instructions.

Comment: The PR has been merged and DAOs can now create and update their tokens metadata through the UI